# Need a 'RaiseEvent' statment to raise an event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, raiseevent

I have a page on the website that display a client details in text boxes.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not page.IsPostBack Then  
        Dim dh As New Datahandler
        Dim CI As ClientInfomation = dh.GETClientInfomationWithClientID(Session("ClientID"))

            txtClientID.Text = Session("ClientID")
            txtCompany.Text = CI.Company
            txtEmail.Text = CI.Email
            txtPassword.text = CI.Password
            dtSubcriptionEndDate.Text = CI.SubscriptionEndDate
            txtContactName.Text = CI.ContactName
            txtTelephoneNum.Text = CI.Telephone.ToString()
    End If
```

The above code works,the code gets the client data from the database in the GETClientInfomationWithClientID(Session("ClientID")) and loads the data into a class, and from the class I load the data into the text boxes.

Here is where my problem starts. A user will now change his details in the text boxes and click the 'Save changes' button invoking the butSaveChanges_Click Event.

```
 Protected Sub butSaveChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butSaveChanges.Click
    Dim dh As New Datahandler
    Dim CI As New ClientInfomation With {.ClientID = txtClientID.Text,
        .Company = txtCompany.Text,
        .ContactName = txtContactName.Text,
        .Email = txtEmail.Text,
        .Password = txtPassword.Text,
        .SubscriptionEndDate = dtSubcriptionEndDate.Text,
        .Telephone = txtTelephoneNum.Text}
    If dh.SaveUserProfileChanegs(CI) = True Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "alert('Changes has been saved')", True)
    Else
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "alert('Changes could not be saved')", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

I just wanted to load the changed text values into the class, and load the class in the SaveUserProfileChanegs(CI) function that updates the new values in the database.

When the butSaveChanges_Click event is invoked I get a "(1) : error BC32022: 'Public Event Click As EventHandler' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event."

Comment: I don't see anything here that could cause this problem, is the error coming from inside SaveUserProfilechanges-method?

Comment: I'm still not sure what was wrong, but it works now. Thanks Esko